# error 'Int32 Parse(System.String)'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

i'm a newbie learn LINQ.
I have some problem in coding. I convert column from string to integer with Convert.Int32. My return function use List. So in my code, i do foreach to move the query data to List, but when i've got an error when i run this code. and the error always on "foreach" with the error message :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

this is my code:

```
var query = from o in _invoiceRepository.Table
  join opv in _opvRepository.Table on o.Id equals opv.InvoiceId
  join pv in _pvRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
  join p in _pRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
  where !o.Deleted && EndDate >= o.CreatedOnUtc && StartDate <= o.CreatedOnUtc
  && opv.SubstitutedBy != null && o.PaidDateUtc != null
  orderby o.GHOrderId, pv.Sku
  select new
  {
    OrderId = o.GHOrderId,
    SKU = pv.Sku,
    Brand = p.BrandII,
    Description = pv.Description,
    Size = p.Size,
    OrderQty = Convert.ToInt32(opv.OrderQuantity)
  };

var query2 = from row in query
             group row by new 
 { row.OrderId, row.SKU, row.Brand, row.Description, row.Size } into result
 select new
 {
   OrderId = result.Key.OrderId,
   SKU = result.Key.SKU,
   Brand = result.Key.Brand,
   Description = result.Key.Description,
   Size = result.Key.Size,
   OrderQty = result.Sum(row => row.OrderQty).ToString("n2")
 };

List<string> _tempdata = new List<string>();
foreach (var order in query.ToList())
{
  _tempdata.Add(order.OrderId.ToString() + ';' + order.SKU.ToString() + ';' +  order.Brand.ToString() + ';' + order.Description.ToString() + ';' + order.Size.ToString() + ';' + order.OrderQty.ToString());
                }
```

i don't know how to solve this... 
I need your help...

Thank you.

Comment: -1. If you'd have google'd this error you'd have found your answer in the first post. Posting unnecessarily large chunks of code with exceptions that have been solved and discussed a million times before will get you nowhere.

Comment: Try replacing this line `OrderQty = Convert.ToInt32(opv.OrderQuantity)` with this: `OrderQty = (int)opv.OrderQuantity`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - converting and casting are 2 completely different things. It will, more than likely, work in majority of the cases here, but depending on the string he passes in he'll just have a different exception to deal with.

Comment: Agh, I didn't notice he said "string". Why on earth is `OrderQuantity` a string? Also, the first google entry I found when searching gave me a different problem, converting a parameter used for where, this is not the same as he's converting a value retrieved by the query, so it cannot simply be moved out of the query.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception states you cannit call this method (nor most other methods) in linq to entities. This is because the code you type has to be convertee to sql and, with the exception of a few hand ported methods, there is no way to convert a .net method to sql

However what you can do is do all of what you need in the linq to entities query except for this and then call .AsEnumerable(). Anything past that statement will be run on the .net side and not on sql server